# C++ pair delete error

Tags: c++, std-pair

****Update:*** * Finally I find the problem. The problem is like this:

```
pair<int,int> *findPair(){
    pair<int,int> *t = new pair<int,int> [10];
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++) // error here
    {
        t[i].first =1;
        t[i].second =2;
    }
    return t;
}

int main() {
    pair<int, int> * tt = findPair();
    tt[1].first =8;
    delete [] tt; // error
    return 0;
}
```

There is segment fault error.  gcc does not show any warning for out of bounds error. In my original code, I use `k` as index of the `pair` array. k changes at each while loop and ends up with a value out of bounds. Thanks you all ans sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: that cannot give segmentation fault. I'm sure your original code is doing something more..

Comment: Code as is works for me.

Comment: "There is no segment *[sic]* fault in this case I will edit later to show my problem"; so you posted a question and code that does not exist? Thanks for playing...

Comment: @ Tomalak  I have a long code that has similar problem. I can not copy the whole code so I extract it to show my original problem but seems I fail to show my original problem from this code.

Comment: Reduce it to the minimum sample that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @Sean: When you create a testcase, that testcase must of course still exhibit the issue.

Comment: Find where it is segfaulting and then come back here and ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code into a .cc file (with the right #include), and this code works just fine.  Are you sure this is where the segmentation fault is at?

If you are using linux, and have no core file, use "ulimit -c unlimited".
Then you can load the core file in gdb to check where the error takes place.